# AJAX request returns as 'undefined'

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to perform a simple AJAX request from a table but when I var dump the result comes back as undefined?

Here is the JS:

```
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","actions/teamData.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I have created a form that select strictly against ID 1 because when trying to do this dynamically with Php it was doing the same so I have set it to 1 to be sure for now:

```
<option value="1">' . $row['name'] . '</option>
```

this is the php doing the request:

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

var_dump($_GET);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM team WHERE id = ' " . $q . " ' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Team name</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

I have a valid connection which has been tested. But the result comes back as:

```
array(1) { ["q"]=> string(9) "undefined" }
```

Comment: print your query and check what are you getting?

Comment: What do you send as the variable str?

Comment: Here `id = ' " . $q . " ' ";` remove the spaces around the number so `id = '" . $q . "' ";`

Comment: Or better still as its a number `WHERE id = $q";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly its still returning as 'undefined' - I copied what you wrote to be double sure.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly im just toying around with this, this isn't going anywhere near production

Comment: Bad habits learned while playing will get to production.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I agree on that point, but I promise it isnt. I just want to see how Ajax plays before I go ahead and scope it properly

Comment: Are you sure that `str` the parameter has actually picked up the `1` the code that calls `showUser(str) {` is not in your example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136326/discussion-between-phpdude-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: Are you sure you have a `name` column in the `team` table?

Comment: @RiggsFolly im such a dumb F - too early in the morning for me. I had `name="teamData" onchange="showUser(this.value)"` on the form and not in the select - face palm

Comment: Haha, we have all done it. Better luck for the rest of the day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array(1) { ["q"]=> string(9) "undefined" }
```

You have got it because javascript variable "str" is undefined. Just check it and send a valid ID.

Start writing you function in a next way:

```
function send_xhr(str) {
  str = str || '';
  if ( !str ) { // str is empty
    // Do something
  }

  // str is not empty
}
```